# Cannot install pyldap with python3.6 pip

Tags: debian, python-3.6, pyldap

I'm trying to install `pyldap` using python3.6 pip in debian:

`pip install pyldap`

But I'm facing this error:

```
----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for pyldap
Running setup.py clean for pyldap
Failed to build pyldap
Installing collected packages: pyldap
Running setup.py install for pyldap ... error
    Complete output from command /home/ssc/VEnvs/newssc/bin/python3.6 -u -c 
"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
eqi2_xn9/pyldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qx8nvwny-record/install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/home/ssc/VEnvs/newssc/include/site/python3.6/pyldap:
    defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
    extra_compile_args:
    extra_objects:
    include_dirs: /usr/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/local/include 
/usr/local/include/sasl
    library_dirs: /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64
    libs: ldap_r
running install
running build
running build_py
    file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying Lib/ldapurl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying Lib/ldif.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying Lib/dsml.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying Lib/slapdtest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/deref.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/libldap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/openldap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/ppolicy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/psearch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/pwdpolicy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/readentry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/sessiontrack.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/simple.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/controls/sss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/controls
copying Lib/ldap/cidict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
copying Lib/ldap/dn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/extop
copying Lib/ldap/extop/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/extop
copying Lib/ldap/extop/dds.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/extop
copying Lib/ldap/filter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
copying Lib/ldap/functions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
copying Lib/ldap/ldapobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
copying Lib/ldap/logger.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
copying Lib/ldap/modlist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
copying Lib/ldap/resiter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
copying Lib/ldap/sasl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/schema/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/schema/models.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/schema/subentry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/schema/tokenizer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/syncrepl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ldap
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
running egg_info
writing Lib/pyldap.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to Lib/pyldap.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to Lib/pyldap.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to Lib/pyldap.egg-info/top_level.txt
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
reading manifest file 'Lib/pyldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
warning: no files found matching 'Modules/LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'Lib/pyldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building '_ldap' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/Modules
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-60vxex/python3.6-3.6.2=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.37 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/ssc/VEnvs/newssc/include/python3.6m -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/Modules/LDAPObject.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: /usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs: No such file or directory
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/ssc/VEnvs/newssc/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
eqi2_xn9/pyldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qx8nvwny-record/install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/home/ssc/VEnvs/newssc/include/site/python3.6/pyldap" failed with error code 1 
in /tmp/pip-build-eqi2_xn9/pyldap/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following command

```
$ sudo apt install python3.6 python3.6-dev gcc build-essential
```